# Undefined when trying to get product

Tags: python, django, ajax

I am working on this project and I am making ajax get request but my product foreign key is coming out as undefined, how do I access the name associated to that foreign key. You can check my code below, what I want to do is to get the product name associated with that forign key but I keep getting undefined and the other field is working fine.

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:"/order/getorder/",
        data:{category:$('#category').val()
    },
        success: function(response){
            for (var key in response.currentorder){

          
            let temp = ''
            temp+="<tr><td>"+response.currentorder[key].order_id+"<td><tr>";
            console.log(response.currentorder[key].product);

           $('#order-table').append(temp);
        }
        },

        
    })
})
```

**VIEW.PY**
def getorder(request):

```
currentorder = PoductOrder.objects.all()
return JsonResponse({"currentorder":list(currentorder.values())})
```

Comment: is Poduct meant to be Product?

Comment: yes it is meant to be

Comment: Does it work if you edit this?